# How can I filter only e-mail sent to the "base" e-mail address?

Tags: gmail-filters

I have an e-mail address `foo@gmail.com`. One site sends e-mail to `foo@gmail.com`, but also to `foo+bar@gmail.com`.

How can I filter only the e-mail sent to `foo@gmail.com`, and not to `foo+bar@gmail.com`?
If I simply target `foo@gmail.com` it also targets the alias.

Comment: With a filter, sorry if the tag wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try negation?

```
-to:foo+bar@gmail.com
```

The minus sign means "NOT".

You might need to clarify:

```
to:foo@gmail.com -to:foo+bar@gmail.com
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it works. I'll accept this if no-one comes up with a better answer.